# Is flutter render infinity size?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I am new in flutter I can't understand that is infinity size render in flutter

If I use container with infinity width then it will render but in box constraints documentation infinity size can't render

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is something constraining the widget, when you set as an example:

```
Container(
 width: double.infinity,
),
```

it will try to take an infinity size, which usually will throw an error to you, but it's constrained so it takes the max possible width.

The `Container` widget is built on top of different multiples widgets such as `ConstrainedBox`, `DecoratedBox`, `Align`, `LimitedBox`... , the `ConstrainedBox` defaults to the  `BoxConstraints.expand()`, check it's source code:

```
    // ...
    child: ConstrainedBox(constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand()),
  );
```

but if you check also the `Scaffold` source code :

```
// ....
final BoxConstraints fullWidthConstraints = looseConstraints.tighten(width: size.width);
```

so trying to expand that `Container` even within infinity, will expand it at maximum on the `fullWidthConstraints` which is, in this case, the screen's width.